# How can I load servlet class for JSP? I keep getting "Class [murach.email.EmailListServlet] isn't a Servlet" after clicking submit made by html form

Tags: java, html, xml, jsp, servlets

This below is the servlet class. I have mapped servlet to a URL in an XML file. I get a:

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Class [murach.email.EmailListServlet] is not a Servlet

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

I have also tried the annotation @WebServlet ("/emailList") but I get the same error.
How can I post /thanks.jsp? I will really appreciate help as I'm a beginner in web development.

package murach.email;

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import murach.business.User;
import murach.data.UserDB;

public class EmailListServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String url = "/index.html";

        // get current action
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action == null) {
            action = "join";  // default action
        }

        // perform action and set URL to appropriate page
        if (action.equals("join")) {
            url = "/index.html";    // the "join" page
        } else if (action.equals("add")) {
            // get parameters from the request
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");

            // store data in User object and save User object in database
            User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email);
            UserDB.insert(user);

            // set User object in request object and set URL
            request.setAttribute("user", user);
            url = "/thanks.jsp";   // the "thanks" page
        }

        // forward request and response objects to specified URL
        getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(url)
                .forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);`enter code here`
    }
}
```

The HTML file looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Murach's Java Servlets and JSP</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Join our email list</h1>
<p>To join our email list, enter your name and
  email address below.</p>
<form action="/emailList" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
  <label class="pad_top">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" required><br>
  <label class="pad_top">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" required><br>
  <label class="pad_top">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" required><br>
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Join Now" class="margin_left">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EmailListServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>murach.email.EmailListServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EmailListServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/emailList</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: <form action="/emailList" method="post">   When the action path begins with a / then it is server relative.  You should try adding your contextPath to the path. Something like  <form action="/yourWebAppName/emailList" method="post">

Comment: Thank you for being will to read the code and providing solution. I tried your method and it does not work. It says murach.email.EmailList is not a servlet in the error 500 page.

Comment: I can not figure out the problem. Maybe you should describe your whole development environment. Are you using Tomcat ? Also, tell us each step that you have taken. Did  you compile EmailListServlet.java to obtain  EmailListServlet.class?   Tell us where you put each file that you are using in your web app.    Are you able to run a simple HelloWorld Servlet?